# Timer based trigger - Testing locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Trying to test CRON trigger function app locally but getting an error:

"The listener for function 'Functions.timer' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Could not create BlobServiceClient to obtain the BlobContainerClient using Connection: Storage."

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "ConnectionStrings:BlobStorageAccount": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "schedule": "*/1 * * * *",
      "name": "reportScheduler",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

and index.js

```
const timer = async function(context, req) {
    context.log("=======PROCESSED=======");
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "HELLO WORLD",
    };
};

module.exports = timer;
```

Really struggling with the documentation specifically around these error messages and translating those into the required changes in local.settings.json

other information:

```
 npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
 func start
```

Comment: I'm confused, it seems as though you've mixed up a HttpTrigger and with a TimerTrigger, no?

Comment: Sorry ignore the name of HttpTrigger it was a function called "HttpTrigger" with a timer based function.json

Comment: Could you please try with this `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` in your host.json!

Answer (score 1):

To run the azure functions (whatever the trigger type), need the azure functions core tools to be installed in your system.
That you can install using `npm` command or executable file installation available in this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools).

**Note:** To install the azure function core tools using `npm` command is: `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true`  and you have to run this command in integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code.

**For Windows, integrated terminal of VS Code is PowerShell, here you can find the integrated terminal:**

[image]

To Create and run the Timer Triggered Function, please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=javascript) for step by step procedure.

I have created the timer trigger JavaScript Azure Function and started to run the function using command `func start`, running successfully:

[image]

I set the CRON expression to every minute for running the function so it is showing the function runs at every minute in the above output console.

**local.settings.json code:**

```
{  
"IsEncrypted": false,  
"Values": {   
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",  
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"  
}
}
```

And
In your **index.js**:

```
const timer = async function(context, req
```

The `req` object refers to http request class so the `req` and `res` objects should be defined in `function.json` class like:

[image]

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node) refers to Azure JavaScript Function Http Trigger.

Comment: Hi sorry, this still doesn't work for me.

Here's a GIF following each step, these steps are actually the ones i completed before i posted this to stackoverflow.

https://imgur.com/a/bc9jRio

Comment: After download v4 from the link in the post onto my machine (not through npm) a slightly different error appears:
The listener for function 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor

Comment: Hello @ShanonJackson, https://i.imgur.com/jFq2K6p.png, I too got the same error `listener for the function was unable to start after some workarounds. After some time, even the error exists, the function is executed as you see here https://i.imgur.com/XuLFhBz.png. I solved this issue by clearing the function process, host process in the task manager and now the function is running successfully both from VS Code, Visual studio as you see here - https://i.imgur.com/oE9rb8r.png

Comment: And there is some error in your index.js. Could you please use the default boilerplate code for the Azure Functions Timer Trigger in JavaScript provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=javascript) and clear the processes func and host in task manager and check the result of running the function!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps if you are working with VS Code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code

also add this in your local.settings.json

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```